# c++ : pass 2d-array by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

I'm getting back into c++ and am having trouble figuring out how to pass a 2D-array to a function. The code below is my current attempt, I've been able to pass vector strings by reference by using:

```
vector<string> g_dictionary;
getDictionaryFromFile(g_dictionary, "d.txt");
...
void getDictionaryFromFile(vector<string> &g_dictionary, string fileName){..}
```

But when I try to do the same thing with my 2d-array like so below, I get an error on the line "solve_point(boardEx);" said a reference of type char & cannot be initialized with a value of type boardEx[5][4]

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void solve_point(char* &board){ 
    printf("solve_point\n");
    //board[2][2] = 'c';
}

int main(){
    char boardEx[5][4];
    solve_point(boardEx);
}
```

Comment: Your edit made you code invalid C++, as C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Which makes my `std::vector` solution the only possible portable and standard solution.

Comment: Please don't edit your post in such a way that answers posted in response to the original post become obsolete.

Comment: Reverted code to make correct answers correct again. It's better to ask a new question than to invalidate an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

The type `char*&` is a reference to a pointer. A "2d" array decays to a pointer to an array.

For your array `boardEx` it will decay to the type `char(*)[4]` which needs to be the type your function accepts:

```
void solve_point(char (*board)[4]) { ... }
```

---

Or you can use templates to deduce the array dimensions

```
template<size_t M, size_t N>
void solve_point(char (&board)[M][N]) { ... }
```

Or use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<std::array<char, 5>, 4> boardEx;

...

void solve_point(std::array<std::array<char, 5>, 4> const& board) { ... }
```

Or use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> boardEx(5, std::vector<char>(4));

...

void solve_point(std::vector<std::vector<char> const& board) { ... }
```

Considering the edit of the question, the solution using `std::vector` is the only portable and standard solution possible.

Comment: thanks, i forgot to include in my question that I'm trying to do this for a dynamically allocated array. i edited my question to reflect that my boardEx is initialized using two int variables instead of hard coded numbers

Answer (score 0):

A reference to a 2D array like you have can be defined using:

```
char (&ref)[5][4] = boardEx;
```

You can change the function to use the same syntax.

```
void solve_point(char (&board)[5][4]){ 
    printf("solve_point\n");
    //board[2][2] = 'c';
}
```

---

For a dynamically allocated array, it will be better to use `std::vector`.

```
int width = 7;
int height = 9;
char boardEx[width][height];
```

is supported by some compilers as an extension but it is not standard C++. Instead, use:

```
int width = 7;
int height = 9;
std::vecotr<std::vector<char>> boardEx(width, std::vector(height));
```

Update `solve_point` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the function that accepts the array either by value or by reference.

For example (by value)

```
void solve_point( char ( *board )[4] ){ 
    printf("solve_point\n");
    //board[2][2] = 'c';
}

int main(){
    char boardEx[5][4];
    solve_point(boardEx);
}
```

Or (by reference)

```
void solve_point(char ( &board )[5][4] ){ 
    printf("solve_point\n");
    //board[2][2] = 'c';
}

int main(){
    char boardEx[5][4];
    solve_point(boardEx);
}
```

In the both cases you can access an element of the array using an expression like this

```
board[i][j] = 'c';
```

Bear in mind that if you have a multidimensional array like for example this

```
T a[N1][N2][N3];
```

where `T` is some type specifier then you can rewrite the declaration the following way

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2][N3];
```

Now to get pointer to elements of the array just substitute `( a[N1] )` for example for `( *pa )`

```
T ( *pa )[N2][N3] = a;
```

To get reference to the array rewrite its declaration like

```
T ( a )[N1][N2][N3];
```

and substitute `( a )` for `( &ra )` like

```
T ( &ra )[N1][N2][N3] = a;
```

If you want to write a function that accepts two dimensional arrays of different sizes by reference then you can write

```
template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
void solve_point( T ( &board )[M][N] ){ 
    //...
}

int main(){
    char boardEx[5][4];
    solve_point(boardEx);
}
```